# SQL Server Group By with Group Concat

Tags: sql-server, group-by, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

I have a table like this

```
Hospital    Insurance   PatientCount
H1          I1          1
H1          I1          2
H2          I1          1
H2          I2          1
```

Want to group this table by insurance as,

```
Hospital    Insurance   PatientCount
H1,H2           I1          4
H2              I2          1
```

Tried using

```
select 
stuff((select ', ' + Hospital
from  Insurances 
where (InsuranceName = i.InsuranceName)
for xml path(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
  ,1,2,'') as Hospitals,
i.InsuranceName,
sum(i.PatientsCount)
from Insurances i
group by i.InsuranceName;
```

Output :

```
Hospital    Insurance   PatientCount
H1,H1,H2        I1          4
H2              I2          1
```

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: the query is working fine expect that i want distinct hospital

Comment: post your desired output below your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to add `DISTINCT` to the `STUFF`.

```
select 
stuff((select DISTINCT ', ' + Hospital
from  A 
where (InsuranceName = i.InsuranceName)
for xml path(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
  ,1,2,'') as Hospitals,
i.InsuranceName,
sum(i.PatientCount)
from A i
group by i.InsuranceName;
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax works:

```
DECLARE @t table
(Hospital char(2), InsuranceName char(2), PatientCount int)
INSERT @t values
('H1','I1',1),
('H1','I1',2),
('H2','I1',1),
('H2','I2',1)


SELECT 
    STUFF(( 
        SELECT ',' + [Hospital] 
        FROM @t t1 
        WHERE t1.InsuranceName = t.InsuranceName
        GROUP BY  [Hospital] 
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') Hospital,
    InsuranceName, 
    SUM(PatientCount) [Patientcount] 
FROM @t t 
GROUP BY InsuranceName
```

Result:

```
Hospital  InsuranceName  Patientcount
H1,H2     I1             3
H2        I2             1
```

Comment: Count is off. Expecting 4

Comment: Thanks a lot t-clausen.dk